# Is it possible find the function $f(n)$?

Tags: limits

Is it possible find the function $f(n)$ ?
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{8 n - 3} - 2^{2n-1}- 3}{2^{4 f(n) - 1} - 2^{f(n)} -1} = 9$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{8n-3}}{2^{4f(n)-1)}} =9 $ since both are leading terms in numerator and denominator,

So $2^{8n-3-4f(n)+1} = 9$ or $2^{8n-3-4f(n)+1} = 2^{\log_2(9)}$ which means that

$8n-2-4f(n) = \log_2(9) $ so $4f(n) = 8n-2-\log_2(9)$ so $f(n) = 2n-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{4} \log_2(9) \approx 2n -0.5788$.

Comment: You had written wrong.'ln' means the logarithm whose base is 'e' .But here the logarithm has base2 .So you must have to write it $log_2$.Please edit it

Comment: @SufaidSaleel right, i will edit